# Change the device major number of /dev/nvme0n1

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On my Linux 5.4.0 system running Ubuntu 18.04, the root filesystem is on device `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, I have:

```
$ ls -l /dev/nvme0n1*
brw-rw---- 1 rood disk 259, 0 Oct 17 12:48 /dev/nvme0n1
brw-rw---- 1 rood disk 259, 1 Oct 17 12:48 /dev/nvme0n1p1
$ grep '^259 ' /proc/devices
259 blkext
```

Some legacy tool I'm trying to requires block device major numbers for mounted filesystems to be smaller than 256.

How do I change the device major number of `/dev/nvme0n1` to a number smaller to than 256? For example, [devices.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) indicates that 240 is available.

Please note that I'm aware that patching the legacy tool and deploying a new version is an option, but in this question I'm explicitly looking for a way to change block device major number of blkext. I'm not interested in workarounds which don't accomplish this.

Maybe what I'm asking for needs recompiling the kernel, because the number 259 is hardcoded (as the symbolic constant `BLOCK_EXT_MAJOR`) in [genhd.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6ad4bf6ea1609fb539a62f10fca87ddbd53a0315/block/genhd.c#L1223). (I'd accept an answer which confirms this.)